# Open with Pandas in Python a .xls file that is corrupted

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xls, cognos

So here is the problem, I'm trying to import a DF from a file downloaded from **COGNOS**. In cognos I select **.CSV** format but always is downloaded the format is **.xls**

It will be very easy to open the .xls file and save as CVS but the problem with that is that the file has more rows than excel so I will lose a lot of data in the process. Also when I open the file in excel it is a warning that the file could be corrupted.

When I'm trying to open the data with `df = pd.read_excel("Time Series 2018-1.xls")` it shows the following problem.

`XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xff\xfeP\x00r\x00o\x00'`

Please HELP

Comment: I'm confused.  Cognos what?  I don't see a "Text" option in the "Run as" menu in Cognos Analytics.  I do see a CSV option (CVS is a drug store).  It looks like the file is not an Excel file, but it has a .xls extension.

Comment: @dougp Thanks, I edited it. You know what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolve it. Just open the file in sublime and save with encoding **UTF-8**. Then just open it with `df = pd.read_csv("Prueba1.xls", sep = "\t", encoding = 'utf8')` because as @dougp said, is just a csv file save with the extension xls.

I guess there is a way to change the encoding in PYTHON but that's for another question.

Comment: So this was a question about Pandas or Python, not Cognos.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. Change the file name, remove spaces and dash then try again
2. follow along with this pandas official [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)